# Get Smtp email from ContactInfo stored in Exchange

Tags: outlook, vsto, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I am using VSTO for my Outlook add-in. Currently I am processing email addresses from all Outlook contacts. There is no problem for instances of ContactInfo if EmailAddress1Type is "SMTP".

But how to get email address for Exchange contact (Email1AddressType = "EX")?

Redemption library is not solution for me as it is expensive just to solve this one problem.

Thank you in advance,

Dusan

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [MSDN reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff867187.aspx) and corresponding sample code:

```cs
private const string Email1EntryIdPropertyAccessor = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/80850102";

PropertyAccessor propertyAccessor = contactItem.PropertyAccessor;
object rawPropertyValue = propertyAccessor.GetProperty(Email1EntryIdPropertyAccessor);
string recipientEntryID = propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(rawPropertyValue);
Recipient recipient = contactItem.Application.Session.GetRecipientFromID(recipientEntryID);
if (null == recipient)
    throw new InvalidOperationException();

bool wasResolved = recipient.Resolve();
if (!wasResolved)
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
ExchangeUser exchangeUser = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
string smtpAddress = exchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
```