# Getting email address of a recipient which is an exchange user

Tags: ms-office, vsto, outlook-addin

In my VSTO Outlook 2007 plug-in, I am able to get the email address of a recipient which is an exchange user. But when I have the following case, it does not return me the smtp email:

1. Add a new Outlook Contact item (in Outlook contacts).
2. The email address of this Contact Item should be an email of an exchange user (any person of your organization, but that is an exchange user).
3. Now when I select this Outlook contact as email recipient and in item send event I cannot get the smtp address.

Below is my code:

```
    Recipient r = mailItem.Recipients[i];
r.Resolve();
//Note, i have different conditions that check the AddressEntryUserType of recipient's 
//address entry object. All other cases work fine. In this case this is 
//olOutlookContactAddressEntry. 
//I have tried the following:

 ContactItem cont = r.AddressEntry.GetContact();
 string email = cont.Email1Address;
 string emailtmp = r.AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101E") as string;
```

Can anyone please help me about what property I should use in this case to get smtp email?

Comment: I am also having this problem and can't get a smtp address from the recipients on an email or appointment item. I can get an address that looks like this only - `Address = "/o=INCORPORATION/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (XXXXXXXXXXXX)/cn=Recipients/cn=username"`

Answer (score 6):

I have found a way to use the ExchangeUser item and resolve the smtp address through that object. This post helped - [Get Smtp email from ContactInfo stored in Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189297/get-smtp-email-from-contactinfo-stored-in-exchange/4668233#4668233)

```cs
    foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in currentAppointment.Recipients)
    {
        Outlook.ExchangeUser exchangeUser = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
        string smtpAddress;
        if (exchangeUser != null)
        {
             smtpAddress = exchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
        }
        else
        {
             smtpAddress = recipient.Address;
        }
    }
```

Comment: GetExchangeUser() requires persistent exchange connection

Comment: I have an Exchange contact where GetExchangeUser returns null. Still the recipient.Address has this wirde /o=FIRM/ou=Some Group/cn=f.name.

Comment: Very helpful when iterate through the recipients and have both cases - email.adress and exhange users email.adrass

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, there were several instances where email addresses wouldn't resolve unless you SAVED the item being sent first. You might try that. Also, are you not getting any "security violation" messages asking for permission to access the user's address book, or have you disabled/worked around all that stuff? I had lots of probs with that that ended up requiring using Redemption for outlook.

Comment: Actually I am not accessing addressbook of Outlook. This is the recipient object of mail item that I am trying to access the email address of. Also, the contact item is already saved before I access the recipient's email address.