# Getting the Internet e-mail address from an Exchange Outlook Contact programmatically?

Tags: outlook

I’m trying to read out the Internet formatted address from an Exchange connected Outlook. I read all contacts from the Outlook Contacts, i.e. not from the Global Address Book (GAB), and the problem is that for all users that are stored in Contacts from the Exchange GAB I’ve only managed to read out the X.500 formatted address which is not useful in this case. For all manually added contacts that are not in the domain of the Exchange server, the Internet address is exported as expected.

Basically I’ve used the following code snippet to enumerate the Contacts:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var outlookApplication = new Application();
    NameSpace mapiNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    MAPIFolder contacts = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

    for (int i = 1; i < contacts.Items.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            ContactItem contact = (ContactItem)contacts.Items[i];
            Console.WriteLine(contact.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine(contact.Email1Address);
            Console.WriteLine(contact.Email2Address);
            Console.WriteLine(contact.Email3Address);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e) { }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Is there any way to extract the Internet address instead of the X.500?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert from `ContactItem` to `AddressEntry` - one email address at a time.

To do this, you need to access the `AddressEntry` via the `Recipient` object model. The only way to retrieve the actual Recipient `EntryID` is by [leveraging the `PropertyAccessor` of the `ContactItem`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668233/175679).

```cs
const string Email1EntryIdPropertyAccessor = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/80850102";
string address = string.Empty;
Outlook.Folder folder = this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts) as Outlook.Folder;
foreach (var contact in folder.Items.Cast<Outlook.ContactItem>().Where(c=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Email1EntryID)))
{
    Outlook.PropertyAccessor propertyAccessor = contact.PropertyAccessor;
    object rawPropertyValue = propertyAccessor.GetProperty(Email1EntryIdPropertyAccessor);
    string recipientEntryID = propertyAccessor.BinaryToString(rawPropertyValue);
    Outlook.Recipient recipient = this.Application.Session.GetRecipientFromID(recipientEntryID);
    if (recipient != null && recipient.Resolve() && recipient.AddressEntry != null)
        address = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress;
}
```

Comment: Has been quite some time since this was answered. Can you plz guide me how I can modify the above code to get `Email2EntryID` and `Email3EntryID`? I have been looking all over the Internet for their GUIDs (looks like that would be the only difference), but haven't found them yet.

Comment: Nevermind. The moment I posted my question, I located a Microsoft page having both IDs. For anyone interested in it, simply change the last part (80850102) with 80950102 for Email2 and 80A50102 for Email3.