# Outlook Add-In : Get Contact from Mail

Tags: outlook, vsto, contacts, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am doing a bit add-in development for outlook 2010 and I'm trying to get the `ContactItems` associated to an email (*`MailItem`*). I think the `MailItem.Links` collection should return what I want, but it's empty. Maybe I'm on the wrong path, but I'm out of ideas at the moment.

I have an `Outlook.MailItem` and I like to get the associated `Outlook.ContactItem`. When you open a mail with outlook and hover over the mail-adresses a contact-popup appears, so the link must be somewhere in the `MailItem`, but I don't know where.

For example, I tried using the `MailItem.Links` collection which says in tooltip that it represents the contacts to which the item is linked.

```
Explorer explorer = application.ActiveWindow() as Explorer;
MailItem mail = explorer.Selection as MailItem;

foreach (Link l in mail.Links)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Link: " + l.Name);
}
```

The `MailItem` so far is correct, I can do whatever I want with it but 
the `MailItem.Links` collection is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the [`MailItem.Recipients`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175516%28v=office.12%29.aspx) collection which contains the addresses where the message will or has been be sent to (*i.e. To, CC, BCC*). You will have to check the [`Recipient.AddressEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176626%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to see if the address exists in the **Contacts Address Book** (CAB) via [`GetContact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175073%28v=office.12%29.aspx), otherwise [you will have to resolve it using `ExchangeUser`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11398836/175679) via [`GetExchangeUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175075%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

The [`AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175079%28v=office.12%29.aspx) will tell you what type of recipient is included in the message - [Exchange User or List, CAB, or basic SMTP address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208051%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Exchange is not an Option, because not every contact in outlook has to be in an exchange. I got a diffrent solution by now which works fine and fast. Besides that, i really don't like my question and tags to be edited.